# Work out values from loaded information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to be able to show a "dynamic return" for each bet that the user has in place, but for some reason none of them work. I have previously asked this question before, but with no luck.

I am hoping that the extra detail in this will be sufficient to help with getting an answer to this at last.

I have hard coded one of the scripts in so to use `odds-1, stake-1`etc, and this worked but the others have not.

If anybody can help with this it would be greatly appreciated.

**JavaScript**

```
        var count_div = 0;
        $("div").each(function () {
            count_div++;
            console.log("Counter: " + count_div);
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < count_div; ++i) {
            $("#stake-" + i).on('keyup', function () {
                var newVal = (parseFloat($("#stake-" + i).val(), 10) * parseFloat($("#__odds-" + i).val(), 10)) + parseFloat($("#stake-" + i).val(), 10) || 0;
                $("#showdynamicreturn-" + i).val(parseFloat(newVal).toFixed(2));
            });
        }
```

**PHP**

```
function readbets( $link, $id, $currentpage, $loggedIn = true ) {
    $idCount = 0;
    $queryBase = "SELECT * FROM `bets` WHERE `user_id` = '%s';";
    if($loggedIn == true) {
        $queryBase2 = sprintf($queryBase, $id);
    }
    else {
        $queryBase2 = sprintf($queryBase, $id);
    }
    $selectQuery = $link->query($queryBase2);
    $return = "<div style='max-height: 680px; overflow: auto;'>";
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($selectQuery)) {
        $idCount++;
        if($result['odds'] == "SP") {
            $odds = "SP";
        }
        else {
            $_odds = explode("/", $result['odds']);
            $odds = $_odds[0] / $_odds[1];
        }            

        $return .= "<div style='border: 1pt solid black; width: 99%;'>";
        $return .= "<h2>" . stripslashes($result['title']) . "</h2>";
        $return .= "<form action='/' method='post'>";
        $return .= "<table class='table table-condensed'>";

        $return .= "<tr><td style='width:50%;'>Sport: </td><td>" . $result['sport'] . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td style='width:50%'>Participant: </td><td>" . stripslashes($result['participant']) . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Market: </td><td>" . stripslashes($result['market']) . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Time: </td><td>" . date("H:i", strtotime($result['bet_till_time'])) . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Odds: </td><td>" . $result['odds'] . "<input type='hidden' value='" . $odds . "' id='__odds-" . $idCount . "' /></td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Stake: </td><td><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>&pound;</span><input style='width:100%' type='text' name='stake' id='stake-" . $idCount . "' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' placeholder='Stake' /></div></td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr id='dynamic_return'><td colspan='10'><center><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon2'>Estimated Return: &pound;</span><input style='width:100%' type='text' id='showdynamicreturn-" . $idCount . "' aria-describedby='basic-addon2' placeholder='0.00' readonly /></div></center></td></tr>";

        if($result['ew_available'] == "true") {
            $return .= "<tr><td><center><label>Each way bet?&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' id='eachWayChk' name='eachWayChk' /></label></center></td>" .  "<td><center><input type='submit' name='submitTo__OpenBets' value='Place Bet' /></center></td></tr>";
        }
        else {                
            $return .=  "<tr><td colspan='10'><center><input type='submit' name='submitTo__OpenBets' value='Place Bet' /></center></td></tr>";
        }

        $return .= "<!-- Hidden fields for the horses information. -->";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='betslip_id' value='" . $result['bet_id'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='sport' value='" . $currentpage . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='eachWay' id='eachWay' value='' />";

        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='odds' value='" . $result['odds'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='ew_odds' value='" . $result['ew_odds'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='sport' value='" . $result['sport'] . "' />";

        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='bettilldate' value='" . $result['bettilldate'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='bettilltime' value='" . $result['bettilltime'] . "' />";

        $return .= "<!-- Area to \"submit a delete\" and remove an item from the bet slip. -->";
        $return .= "<tr><td colspan='100%'><center><input type='submit' name='delete_betslip_item' value='Delete this bet' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')\" /></center></td></tr>";
        $return .= "</table>";
        $return .= "</form>";
        $return .= "</div><br>";
    }
    $return .= "</div>";
    return $return;
}
```

**Generated HTML**

```
<div style='border: 1pt solid black; width: 99%; border-radius: 25pt;'>
    <h2>Cyprus v Wales - Match Betting</h2>
    <form action='/' method='post'>
        <table class='table table-condensed'>
            <tr>
                <td style='width: 50%;'>Sport: </td>
                <td>Football</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style='width: 50%'>Participant: </td>
                <td>Cyprus</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Market: </td>
                <td>Euro 2016</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Time: </td>
                <td>19:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Odds: </td>
                <td>19/5<input type='hidden' value='3.8' id='__odds-3' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Stake: </td>
                <td>
                    <div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>&pound;</span><input style='width: 100%' type='text' name='stake' id='stake-3' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' placeholder='Stake' /></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='dynamic_return'>
                <td colspan='10'>
                    <center><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon2'>Estimated Return: &pound;</span><input style='width:100%' type='text' id='showdynamicreturn-4' aria-describedby='basic-addon2' placeholder='0.00' readonly /></div></center>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='10'>
                    <center><input type='submit' name='submitTo__OpenBets' value='Place Bet' /></center>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Hidden fields for the horses information. -->
            <input type='hidden' name='betslip_id' value='13' /><input type='hidden' name='sport' value='' /><input type='hidden' name='eachWay' id='eachWay' value='' /><input type='hidden' name='odds' value='19/5' /><input type='hidden' name='ew_odds' value='' /><input type='hidden' name='sport' value='Football' /><input type='hidden' name='bettilldate' value='' /><input type='hidden' name='bettilltime' value='' /><!-- Area to "submit a delete" and remove an item from the bet slip. --><tr>
                <td colspan='100%'>
                    <center><input type='submit' name='delete_betslip_item' value='Delete this bet' onclick="return confirm( 'Are you sure you want to delete this?' )" /></center>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about what you intend to do. Also I couldn't find in your code elements with `id` starting with `stake-`, `__odds-` or `showdynamicreturn-`. I think part of your code is missing here and you need to be more clear about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: where is `count_div` defined

Comment: @atmd, it is defined directly above the `each` function after document.ready

Comment: so there is more to your code then you've put here? why not put it all?

Comment: @atmd, I shall add it

Comment: Great. Also, your html is invalid, you are missing closing tags, try putting it through a validator

Comment: @atmd, aologies for that, I updated my answer and missed some code to delete, I put the wrong code in originally

Comment: Your PHP code has a number of flaws that indicate bad practice. Your usage of `stripslashes()` is wrong - you shouldn't need it here; if you have stray slashes in your result data when it comes out of the DB then your code for inserting that data into the DB is flawed. What you probably do need instead is `htmlentities()`. In any case `stripslashes()` and `addslashes()` should be avoided in most cases as they have major flaws which leave them open to being hacked. Also for your DB query, you should use `mysqli_prepare()` and `mysqli_bind_param()` to add the param to the query, not `sprintf()`.

Comment: @Simba, htmlentities did not work for me and due to the nature of the data, I needed a way to escape the strings and keep them there so I could use them later, hence why I chose `stripslashes` and `addslashes`

Comment: @Simba, also `mysqli_real_escape_string` did not work

Comment: Just to be clear: If you're using `stripslashes()` and `addslashes()` in relation to data that's going in and out of a database then your system is insecure and vulnerable. They are not suitable functions to use in this context. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is suitable, but that also wouldn't be necessary if you use Prepared Statements (ie `mysqli_prepare()` and `mysqli_bind_param()` per my previous comment).

Comment: I think we're getting off-topic from the original question here, but this is a serious issue so I recommend you take your code over to the [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site and ask a more direct question there about how to improve it, particularly with regard to database security. You'll need to supply other parts of your PHP code as well to give the full picture.

Comment: What if what's being loaded into the database has an apostophe in it? Will `mysqli_prepare` handle this?

Comment: want to help. but its not clear enough.how are you handling the post data.

Comment: answered .hope it helps.if so please mark it as answer. if not just let me know. i need the bounty :)

Comment: `count_div = $('div').length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it. Instead of adding functions with id specific in the DOM we can use class specific.

So assign classes to your following tags

```
<input type='hidden' value='3.8' id='__odds-3' />
<input style='width: 100%' type='text' name='stake' id='stake-3' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' placeholder='Stake' />
<input style='width:100%' type='text' id='showdynamicreturn-4' aria-describedby='basic-addon2' placeholder='0.00' readonly />
```

Add Classes dynamically when you are generating this HTML tags by your javascript. just assign it. So the tags should be look like the below

```
<input class="odds" type='hidden' value='3.8' id='__odds-3' />
<input class="stake" style='width: 100%' type='text' name='stake' id='stake-3' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' placeholder='Stake' />
<input class="showdynamicreturn" style='width:100%' type='text' id='showdynamicreturn-4' aria-describedby='basic-addon2' placeholder='0.00' readonly />
```

After that we can use `Closest` using jquery and add a class specific function. It'll do the rest.

So the javascript code will be look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".stake").on('keyup', function () {
            var newVal = (parseFloat($(this).val(), 10) * parseFloat($(this).closest(".table").find(".odds").val(), 10)) + parseFloat($(this).val(), 10) || 0;

            $(this).closest(".table").find(".showdynamicreturn" ).val(parseFloat(newVal).toFixed(2));
        });
});
```

This code will work for all the tables no matter how many you have and it'll give the result only on the desired estimated return textbox

The working fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/6fgw91zx/

Just check it and let me know if it is helpful

Comment: What happens when there are multiple `class="stake"`? Surely the jQ will take every single one and put it all into the same `class="showdynamicreturn"` over and over as there will be one for each item?

Comment: no.. it'll check for the closest.. It means it is checking for its own parent and update only `class="showdynamicreturn"` which is a sibling to its own. So obviously this will update only the corresponding textbox no matter how many `class="stake"` is there

Comment: check the fiddle and give try with multiple stake with your dynamic javascript code all with the same class.. It'll work

Comment: Check this fiddle it is having multiple stake as you are expecting

http://jsfiddle.net/rajeshkannan007/oufeyctb/

Comment: And the bounty goes to **DRUM ROLL** @Rajeshkannan! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry for the stupid first question on this, I am relatively new to jQ and as such am not entirely sure what's going on with the code

Comment: No probs Sam. Everyone is in the learning process. Stackoverflow made a platform to share it

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is in the usage of variable i in your "for" cycle. You are using this variable in a closure - if you put alert(i) into the keyup callback, it will always give you the total number of divs, no matter which value you changed.

To fix this, I'd suggest you to bind keyup method in more clever way, something like this:

```
        $("body").delegate('.stake', 'keyup', function () {
            var $input = $(this);
            var i = parseInt($input.attr('id').replace('stake-', ''));
            var newVal = (parseFloat($input.val(), 10) * parseFloat($("#__odds-" + i).val(), 10)) + parseFloat($input.val(), 10) || 0;
            $("#showdynamicreturn-" + i).val(parseFloat(newVal).toFixed(2));
        });
```

To make it work you need to add "stake" class to your input element

Answer (score 2):

As you have declared $idCount=0 inside the function, each time when the function is called it is re assigned with value 0. So to make it work the way we want initialize the $idCount with value zero globbaly outside the function prototype one time and above calling the "readbets" function. it could be somethinglike this.
I am not sure whether this is what you are trying to do but i think it is.hope this helps.

```
$idCount=0;
//not clear enough if its for multiple users uncomment the foreach loop
//foreach ($id as $id){
//each time the idCount incements and the value is stored for next increment.
echo readbets( $link, $id, $currentpage, $loggedIn);
//}
//below is same as your code except that i removed $idCount = 0;
function readbets( $link, $id, $currentpage, $loggedIn = true ) {
//$idCount = 0;
    $queryBase = "SELECT * FROM `bets` WHERE `user_id` = '%s';";
    if($loggedIn == true) {
        $queryBase2 = sprintf($queryBase, $id);
    }
    else {
        $queryBase2 = sprintf($queryBase, $id);
    }
    $selectQuery = $link->query($queryBase2);
    $return = "<div style='max-height: 680px; overflow: auto;'>";
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($selectQuery)) {
        $idCount++;
        if($result['odds'] == "SP") {
            $odds = "SP";
        }
        else {
            $_odds = explode("/", $result['odds']);
            $odds = $_odds[0] / $_odds[1];
        }            

        $return .= "<div style='border: 1pt solid black; width: 99%;'>";
        $return .= "<h2>" . stripslashes($result['title']) . "</h2>";
        $return .= "<form action='/' method='post'>";
        $return .= "<table class='table table-condensed'>";

        $return .= "<tr><td style='width:50%;'>Sport: </td><td>" . $result['sport'] . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td style='width:50%'>Participant: </td><td>" . stripslashes($result['participant']) . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Market: </td><td>" . stripslashes($result['market']) . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Time: </td><td>" . date("H:i", strtotime($result['bet_till_time'])) . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Odds: </td><td>" . $result['odds'] . "<input type='hidden' value='" . $odds . "' id='__odds-" . $idCount . "' /></td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Stake: </td><td><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>&pound;</span><input style='width:100%' type='text' name='stake' id='stake-" . $idCount . "' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' placeholder='Stake' /></div></td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr id='dynamic_return'><td colspan='10'><center><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon2'>Estimated Return: &pound;</span><input style='width:100%' type='text' id='showdynamicreturn-" . $idCount . "' aria-describedby='basic-addon2' placeholder='0.00' readonly /></div></center></td></tr>";

        if($result['ew_available'] == "true") {
            $return .= "<tr><td><center><label>Each way bet?&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' id='eachWayChk' name='eachWayChk' /></label></center></td>" .  "<td><center><input type='submit' name='submitTo__OpenBets' value='Place Bet' /></center></td></tr>";
        }
        else {                
            $return .=  "<tr><td colspan='10'><center><input type='submit' name='submitTo__OpenBets' value='Place Bet' /></center></td></tr>";
        }

        $return .= "<!-- Hidden fields for the horses information. -->";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='betslip_id' value='" . $result['bet_id'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='sport' value='" . $currentpage . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='eachWay' id='eachWay' value='' />";

        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='odds' value='" . $result['odds'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='ew_odds' value='" . $result['ew_odds'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='sport' value='" . $result['sport'] . "' />";

        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='bettilldate' value='" . $result['bettilldate'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='bettilltime' value='" . $result['bettilltime'] . "' />";

        $return .= "<!-- Area to \"submit a delete\" and remove an item from the bet slip. -->";
        $return .= "<tr><td colspan='100%'><center><input type='submit' name='delete_betslip_item' value='Delete this bet' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')\" /></center></td></tr>";
        $return .= "</table>";
        $return .= "</form>";
        $return .= "</div><br>";
    }
    $return .= "</div>";
    return $return;
}
```

Or you could simply check whether its set and its value is 0, if not just leave it like that else set it to zero. although it looks pretty this way it will each time check whether its assigned or not.

```
function readbets( $link, $id, $currentpage, $loggedIn = true ) {
    //just added this if else to your code nothing else
    $idCount = isset($idCount)?$idCount:$idCount=0;
    //edit end
    $queryBase = "SELECT * FROM `bets` WHERE `user_id` = '%s';";
    if($loggedIn == true) {
        $queryBase2 = sprintf($queryBase, $id);
    }
    else {
        $queryBase2 = sprintf($queryBase, $id);
    }
    $selectQuery = $link->query($queryBase2);
    $return = "<div style='max-height: 680px; overflow: auto;'>";
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($selectQuery)) {
        $idCount++;
        if($result['odds'] == "SP") {
            $odds = "SP";
        }
        else {
            $_odds = explode("/", $result['odds']);
            $odds = $_odds[0] / $_odds[1];
        }            

        $return .= "<div style='border: 1pt solid black; width: 99%;'>";
        $return .= "<h2>" . stripslashes($result['title']) . "</h2>";
        $return .= "<form action='/' method='post'>";
        $return .= "<table class='table table-condensed'>";

        $return .= "<tr><td style='width:50%;'>Sport: </td><td>" . $result['sport'] . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td style='width:50%'>Participant: </td><td>" . stripslashes($result['participant']) . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Market: </td><td>" . stripslashes($result['market']) . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Time: </td><td>" . date("H:i", strtotime($result['bet_till_time'])) . "</td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Odds: </td><td>" . $result['odds'] . "<input type='hidden' value='" . $odds . "' id='__odds-" . $idCount . "' /></td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr><td>Stake: </td><td><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>&pound;</span><input style='width:100%' type='text' name='stake' id='stake-" . $idCount . "' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' placeholder='Stake' /></div></td></tr>";
        $return .= "<tr id='dynamic_return'><td colspan='10'><center><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon2'>Estimated Return: &pound;</span><input style='width:100%' type='text' id='showdynamicreturn-" . $idCount . "' aria-describedby='basic-addon2' placeholder='0.00' readonly /></div></center></td></tr>";

        if($result['ew_available'] == "true") {
            $return .= "<tr><td><center><label>Each way bet?&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' id='eachWayChk' name='eachWayChk' /></label></center></td>" .  "<td><center><input type='submit' name='submitTo__OpenBets' value='Place Bet' /></center></td></tr>";
        }
        else {                
            $return .=  "<tr><td colspan='10'><center><input type='submit' name='submitTo__OpenBets' value='Place Bet' /></center></td></tr>";
        }

        $return .= "<!-- Hidden fields for the horses information. -->";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='betslip_id' value='" . $result['bet_id'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='sport' value='" . $currentpage . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='eachWay' id='eachWay' value='' />";

        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='odds' value='" . $result['odds'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='ew_odds' value='" . $result['ew_odds'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='sport' value='" . $result['sport'] . "' />";

        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='bettilldate' value='" . $result['bettilldate'] . "' />";
        $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='bettilltime' value='" . $result['bettilltime'] . "' />";

        $return .= "<!-- Area to \"submit a delete\" and remove an item from the bet slip. -->";
        $return .= "<tr><td colspan='100%'><center><input type='submit' name='delete_betslip_item' value='Delete this bet' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')\" /></center></td></tr>";
        $return .= "</table>";
        $return .= "</form>";
        $return .= "</div><br>";
    }
    $return .= "</div>";
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that the idcount and `i` don't match correctly - probably because you have other divs in the code.

You can massively simplify what you are doing and remove the loop where the error crops up by including all the relevant stuff (the idcount) in the HTML.

Change the outputted HTML to include the "id number" `idCount` in a data element and not by bastardizing the ID. e.g.

```
// replace the input element with the one below:
<input style='width: 100%' type='text' name='stake' id='stake' data-idnumber='" . $idCount . "' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' placeholder='Stake' />
```

Then you can run your jQuery selector as follows (without any looping - the one line below replaces your entire code block provided above)

```
$("#stake").on('keyup', function () {
    var i = parseInt($(this).data("idnumber") , 10);
    var orginalVal = parseFloat($(this).val(), 10);        
    var newVal = orginalVal  * parseFloat($("#__odds-" + i).val(), 10)) + orginalVal || 0;
    $("#showdynamicreturn-" + i).val(parseFloat(newVal).toFixed(2));
});
```

Notes:

- there are other ways; you could loop the divs as you've done (but best to go off a less generic selector that "div", e.g. a class name) and then use "find" to get the correct elements to update / process.
- Simba's comments about using HTMLSpecialChars and prepared statements (and not relying on strip tags) are bang on the money - if HTMLSpecialChars isn't working correctly. Once you have this issue sorted, please follow though his comments for both your own safety and also sanity, then your data is in a mess that you'll regret later on! Should fix it now before you get so far down the line you can't fix it. Prepared statements also a good practice to get into earlier rather than later.

Comment: You're missing an opening quote `data-idnumber=" . $idCount . "'` should be `data-idnumber='" . $idCount . "'`. I'm on board with use of the data attr, but from what i can see the input is drawn from within a while loop, which means you'll have multiple inputs with the same `id`

Answer (score 0):

Check this working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h09z4ueL/)

changed little bit of code like in the below

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
            $("#stake-3").on('keyup', function () {
                var newVal = (parseFloat($("#stake-3").val(), 10) * parseFloat($("#__odds-3").val(), 10)) + parseFloat($("#stake-3").val(), 10) || 0;
                $("#showdynamicreturn-4").val(parseFloat(newVal).toFixed(2));
            });
      });
```

Check it and let me know if it is helpful

Comment: Afraid it isn't, that's a hard coded value of the `$("#stake-" + i)` that I require, For what I need, I need to use a dynamic version of this, I have used this I my code and it has worked previously, but what I require is it to NOT be hard coded, I have stated this in my question description.